# Does creating a XAML with XAML.cs have more overhead than just a cs?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So we have extended Infragistics controls and WPF tool kit controls in two different ways.

Method #1: We create a new user control with a XAML and XAML.cs file. Then in here we either extend the target control or we wrap the target control in order to expand on its functionality.

Method #2: We create a CS file and extend the target control then expand its functionality here.

Example:

I have a text box that I use 100 times in my wpf application. Every single tool box I want to have functionality X or Style Y.

Does it cost more in overhead to take method #1 or method #2?

I am inclined to believe though it might be slightly more overhead that method #1 is the prefered path but before I can take this to my team I need something a little more concrete for an answer.

Comment: There are more things to take into account, not just UserControl vs custom control. Take a look at the [Control Authoring Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx) article on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at pure performance, I think that using a .XAMl.CS file may be a little slower due to the call to initializeComponents() but honestly that's negligible.

The real gain comes from moving the UI logic out of the .XAML.CS file is that you can start taking advantage of the lookless control model (http://drwpf.com/blog/2009/05/12/itemscontrol-l-is-for-lookless/.)

This is the pattern that Microsoft uses. If ever were to look at the source code for any of the default WPF controls (button, for example) you'll notice they don't have a xaml.cs file. Instead, Microsoft ships a default visual representation with the framework, but you can change the way the button looks by adding a style to a resource dictionary for that control that sets a new template.

For example, I can change the button style so that all the buttons in my app are yellow squares, without having to subclass button and set the properties in the constructor, which will cut down on the amount of classes you have to make.

Comment: What an insightful answer! Thank you so much :-D